# Do not get expected output using SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

Data rows retrieve from database is as below:

```
Row | Limit | Color
1   | 0     | Yellow
2   | 50    | Orange
3   | 90    | Green
4   | 100   | Red
```

A table with two columns are created. The expression for each column is as below:

Column 1:

```
=Fields!Color.Value
```

Column 2:

```
=Switch(Fields!Row.Value=1, Fields!Limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(2, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Limit.Value, "LimitDs"), Fields!Row.Value=2, Fields!Limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(3, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Limit.Value, "LimitDs"), Fields!Row.Value=3, Fields!Limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(4, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Limit.Value, "LimitDs"), Fields!Row.Value <> 1 and Fields!Row.Value <> 2 and Fields!Row.Value <> 3, ">" & Fields!Limit.Value)
```

Output get as below:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
Yellow   | 0-50
Orange   | 50-90
Green    | 90-100
Green    | 90-100
```

In fact, my expected output is as below:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
Yellow   | 0-50
Orange   | 50-90
Green    | 90-100
Red      | >100
```

Anyone can help on this?

Comment: instead of `Fields!Row.Value <> 1 and Fields!Row.Value <> 2 and Fields!Row.Value <> 3,` try `True, ">" & Fields!Limit.Value`. This is the SSRS Else condition for Switch

Comment: Thanks MigueIH, but the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you check for the last possibility first, the other conditions can be expressed as one (Fields!Row.Value + 1):

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Lookup(Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Limit.Value, "LimitDs")), 
    ">" & Fields!Limit.Value, 
    Fields!Limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(Fields!Row.Value + 1, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Limit.Value, "LimitDs"))
```

Comment: Thanks Hannover Fist. But it still doesn't work as my expected.

Comment: So `Fields!Row.Value=4, ">" & Fields!Limit.Value)` wouldn't work in place of `Fields!Row.Value <> 1 and Fields!Row.Value <> 2 and Fields!Row.Value <> 3, ">" & Fields!Limit.Value)`?

Comment: @MiguelH - that would work too but mine works regardless of how many there are and it combines the others into a single statement.

Comment: @Donna - I think the problem isn't with the formula but why you are getting two **Green**s in your **Output** data in the first place. Try putting a new table with just the **Color** field to make sure the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The DataSet used for Column 1 needs to be separate from the expression in column 2: ie DataSet1 for column 1 and DataSet 2 for the expression in column 2. Your expression for column 2 needs to be amended to the following:
=Switch(Fields!row.Value=1, Fields!limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(2, Fields!row.Value, Fields!limit.Value, "DataSet5"), 
        Fields!row.Value=2, Fields!limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(3, Fields!row.Value, Fields!limit.Value, "DataSet5"), 
        Fields!row.Value=3, Fields!limit.Value & " - " & Lookup(4, Fields!row.Value, Fields!limit.Value, "DataSet5"), 
        Fields!row.Value=4, " > " & Fields!limit.Value )